# Stacked Bar Graph in Pandas/iPython

Tags: pandas, ipython, bar-chart

Trying to create a stacked bar chart in Pandas/iPython

Raw data is below:

```
    Date1      ProductID1   Count
0   2015-06-21      102     5449
1   2015-06-21      107     5111
2   2015-06-22      102     9083
3   2015-06-22      107     7978
4   2015-06-23      102     21036
5   2015-06-23      107     20756
```

Used the following to set index:

```
Table1.set_index(['Date1'],inplace=True)
display(Table1)
```

Used the following to unstack the data to prep for plotting

```
 Table1_Unstacked = Table1.unstack()
 display(Table1_Unstacked)
```

(Note: Nothing displays in this command so I'm assuming this is where it's failing but I can't figure out why).

Trying to get the table in this format:

```
                       Count     
      Date1          ProductID1 
                    102      107    
    2015-06-21      5449     5111
    2015-06-22      9083     7978
    2015-06-23      21036    20756
```

Then used the following to display the results and it's not displaying as desired.

```
Table1_Unstacked.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Results are below. I'm trying to get it to display 3 "bars" (one for each day with the counts for 102 and 107 "stacked" on top of each other but right now it's not displaying anything stacked and it's displaying ProductID1 and then counts separately. Attaching a pic of graph but it may not let me post it. I feel like I'm making a silly mistake but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.pivot_table()`.

```
import pandas as pd

pivot = pd.pivot_table(Table1.reset_index(), index='Date1', columns='ProductID1', values='Count')

pivot
Out[44]: 
ProductID1    102    107
Date1                   
2015-06-21   5449   5111
2015-06-22   9083   7978
2015-06-23  21036  20756


pivot.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]